# Retrieve content of a key from Azure keyvault in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-keyvault

I would like to retrieve content of a key that is on the Azure key vault via python. This block of code returns me the key properties, and not the content (I would like to have the binary content of the key):

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.keys import KeyClient

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

key_client = KeyClient(vault_url="https://my-key-vault.vault.azure.net/", credential=credential)
key = key_client.get_key("key-name")
print(key.name)
```

I have found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-python?tabs=azure-cli#create-the-sample-code) code for retrieving secrets from Key vault, but I need to retrieve the Key

How can I retrieve (binary) content of a key from azure keyvault?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I retrieve (binary) content of a key from azure keyvault?

Simple answer is that you cannot. Once a key is stored in KeyVault, its value cannot be retrieved. That's the whole purpose of storing a Key in a KeyVault.

Comment: Oh, I thought the `n` value in `JsonWebKey` for example for an RSA key is the key byte. isnt it? in such a format:
`   "key": {
    "crv": null,
    "d": null,
    "dp": null,
    "dq": null,
    "e": "AQAB",
    "k": null,
    "keyOps": [
      "unwrapKey",
      "wrapKey"
    ],
    "kid": "",
    "kty": "RSA-HSM",
    "n": "pvSXpiGxxxxxxxxxxxyHWfygfWt6zEuEnNmaf4OEkQryxxxxxxxxx8QonWHSqjHcK+3Zlg7xxxxxxJgGWs53+mvaI0iFNeNnMadB+9zOop/c+aa5yMFjTHHSyXAminI6x4Q==",
  },`

Comment: Not an expert here but `n` is not the key byte. It is the modulus of the public key. I thought you wanted to get the private key stored in KeyVault.

Comment: To be honest I want to retrieve the Key byte (if it is possible) of an AES key which is in manged hsm and use it in [aes_encrypt function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/functions/aes_encrypt) as `key` input parameter

Comment: I don't think you can.